# Plot is discontinuous (it shouldn't be)

Tags: plotting

```
Plot[{(E^x)^(-2 I π) Hypergeometric2F1[-2 I π - 2 I Sqrt[2] π, -2 I π + 2 I Sqrt[2] π, 
                                       1 - 4 I π, -E^x] + 
      (E^x)^ (2 I π)  Hypergeometric2F1[2 I π - 2 I Sqrt[2] π, 2 I π + 2 I Sqrt[2] π, 
                                      1 + 4 I π, -E^x]}, 
      {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Why? How to fix?

Comment: The leading term in the asymptotic expansion for x<0 is 2 Cos[2 Pi x]. For x>0, the expression is much more complicated but the leading term is A Cos[2 Sqrt[2] Pi x+d] where A~1.7 and d~0.5. The transition between these asymptotic behaviours is in over -3 < x < 3.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The numerical evaluation of your argument function leads to very small imaginary parts in the result that are due to numerical inaccuracy. Remove them by wrapping the argument of `Plot` in `Chop` (see [its documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html)):

```
Plot[Chop[(E^x)^(-2 I π) Hypergeometric2F1[-2 I π - 
      2 I Sqrt[2] π, -2 I π + 2 I Sqrt[2] π, 
     1 - 4 I π, -E^x] + (E^x)^(2 I π) Hypergeometric2F1[
     2 I π - 2 I Sqrt[2] π, 2 I π + 2 I Sqrt[2] π, 
     1 + 4 I π, -E^x]], {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Interesting. It is a miracle that it evaluates it to be purely real for anywhere at all.

Comment: @grdgfgr it doesn't have to evaluate to purely real to appear plotted. The ratio of imaginary to real part just has to be below some threshold. See e.g. `Plot[Sin[x]+10^-15I,{x,-3,3}]`, it'll be plotted where the real part is greater than about `0.1`.

Answer (score 17):

Good way: use a higher setting of `WorkingPrecision`.

```
Plot[{Exp[x]^(-2 I π) Hypergeometric2F1[-2 I π (Sqrt[2] + 1), 2 I π (Sqrt[2] - 1),
                                        1 - 4 I π, -Exp[x]] +
      Exp[x]^(2 I π) Hypergeometric2F1[-2 I π (Sqrt[2] - 1), 2 I π (Sqrt[2] + 1),
                                        1 + 4 I π, -Exp[x]]}, {x, -10, 10}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

**Best way**: [stand on the shoulders of giants](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHypergeometricTransformations.html):

```
Plot[(1 + Exp[x]) (Exp[x]^(-2 I π) Hypergeometric2F1[
     1 + 2 I π (Sqrt[2] - 1), 1 - 2 I π (Sqrt[2] + 1), 1 - 4 I π, -Exp[x]] +
     Exp[x]^(2 I π) Hypergeometric2F1[1 + 2 I π (Sqrt[2] + 1),
     1 - 2 I π (Sqrt[2] - 1), 1 + 4 I π, -Exp[x]]), {x, -10, 10}]
```

Comment: Now your gedanken model got  the Gedanken Graphics(tm) upgrade. Nice!

Comment: Nono, I am on a borrowed computer again for today, @bel. :)

Answer (score 8):

I think this question has been asked before, the short answer is the function is at least not real for numerical evaluation.

```
Table[{(E^x)^(-2 I π) Hypergeometric2F1[-2 I π - 
      2 I Sqrt[2] π, -2 I π + 2 I Sqrt[2] π, 
     1 - 4 I π, -E^x] + (E^x)^(2 I π) Hypergeometric2F1[
     2 I π - 2 I Sqrt[2] π, 2 I π + 2 I Sqrt[2] π, 
     1 + 4 I π, -E^x]}, {x, 1.1, 1.15, 0.01}]
```

> ```
> {{-0.217093 + 2.55351*10^-15 I}, {-0.073033 + 
>    2.55351*10^-15 I}, {0.0715313 + 3.33067*10^-15 I}, {0.2156 + 
>    1.9984*10^-15 I}, {0.358176 + 3.10862*10^-15 I}, {0.498267 + 
>    4.66294*10^-15 I}}
> ```

You can just plot the real part:

```
Plot[{Re[(E^x)^(-2 I π) Hypergeometric2F1[-2 I π - 
       2 I Sqrt[2] π, -2 I π + 2 I Sqrt[2] π, 
      1 - 4 I π, -E^x] + (E^x)^(2 I π) Hypergeometric2F1[
      2 I π - 2 I Sqrt[2] π, 2 I π + 2 I Sqrt[2] π, 
      1 + 4 I π, -E^x]]}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]