# Why does the plot of a continuous function have gaps

Tags: plotting

[image]

```
Plot[-s*(-q^2/(2*s) + 
    q*(p - 1)/
      s + (-(p*s - 2*s + 1)/(2*s^2) - 
       Sqrt [s^5*(s - 1)]*(p - 2)/(2*s^4))*
     Log[(2*s^2*(-(p*s - 2*s + 1)/(2*s^2) - 
            Sqrt[s^5*(s - 1)]*(p - 2)/(2*s^4)) + 1)/(p*s - 
         2*s)] - (-(p*s - 2*s + 1)/(2*s^2) - 
       Sqrt[s^5*(s - 1)]*(p - 2)/(2*s^4))*
     Log [q + (2*
           s^2*(-(p*s - 2*s + 1)/(2*s^2) - 
             Sqrt [s^5*(s - 1)]*(p - 2)/(2*s^4)) + 1)/(p*s - 
          2*s)] + (-(p*s - 2*s + 1)/(2*s^2) + 
       Sqrt[s^5*(s - 1)]*(p - 2)/(2*s^4))*
     Log [(2*s^2*(-(p*s - 2*s + 1)/(2*s^2) + 
            Sqrt[s^5*(s - 1)]*(p - 2)/(2*s^4)) + 1)/(p*s - 
         2*s)] - (-(p*s - 2*s + 1)/(2*s^2) + 
       Sqrt[s^5*(s - 1)]*(p - 2)/(2*s^4))*
     Log[q + (2*
           s^2*(-(p*s - 2*s + 1)/(2*s^2) + 
             Sqrt[s^5*(s - 1)]*(p - 2)/(2*s^4)) + 1)/(p*s - 
          2*s)]), {q, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]
```

Comment: What values did `p` and `s` have?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87504/plot-is-discontinuous-it-shouldnt-be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comment said, you should provide values for `p` and `s` so one can reproduce the result.
But while waiting for coeffee, I tried few random values for `p` and `s` and reproduced the problem. The fix is to add `Chop` as this is result of small complex values that shows up.

```
ClearAll[p, s, q];
p = .1;
s = .2;
f := -s*(-q^2/(2*s) + 
     q*(p - 1)/
       s + (-(p*s - 2*s + 1)/(2*s^2) - 
        Sqrt[s^5*(s - 1)]*(p - 2)/(2*s^4))*
      Log[(2*s^2*(-(p*s - 2*s + 1)/(2*s^2) - 
             Sqrt[s^5*(s - 1)]*(p - 2)/(2*s^4)) + 1)/(p*s - 
          2*s)] - (-(p*s - 2*s + 1)/(2*s^2) - 
        Sqrt[s^5*(s - 1)]*(p - 2)/(2*s^4))*
      Log[q + (2*
            s^2*(-(p*s - 2*s + 1)/(2*s^2) - 
              Sqrt[s^5*(s - 1)]*(p - 2)/(2*s^4)) + 1)/(p*s - 
           2*s)] + (-(p*s - 2*s + 1)/(2*s^2) + 
        Sqrt[s^5*(s - 1)]*(p - 2)/(2*s^4))*
      Log[(2*s^2*(-(p*s - 2*s + 1)/(2*s^2) + 
             Sqrt[s^5*(s - 1)]*(p - 2)/(2*s^4)) + 1)/(p*s - 
          2*s)] - (-(p*s - 2*s + 1)/(2*s^2) + 
        Sqrt[s^5*(s - 1)]*(p - 2)/(2*s^4))*
      Log[q + (2*
            s^2*(-(p*s - 2*s + 1)/(2*s^2) + 
              Sqrt[s^5*(s - 1)]*(p - 2)/(2*s^4)) + 1)/(p*s - 2*s)]);
Plot[f, {q, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now see what happens when adding `Chop`

```
 Plot[Chop[f], {q, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `Chop` is not needed if you use exact values for your `p` and `s`: 

`Plot[Evaluate[(expr /. {p -> 1/10, s -> 1/5})], {q, 0, 1}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon  That is true. OP must have used real values.

Answer (score 0):

Better plot the real part with `Re` (nulling the spurious imaginary part) instead of using `Chop` (nulling the spurious imaginary part if it is below a threshold; but also nulling the real part if it gets too small):

```
Plot[Re[f], {q, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]
```